# Can't install packages globally

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, terminal

Hi whenever I try to install or run a command globally using npm my terminal always displays an error of the following:
[image]

Does anyone know why? I was trying to install ionic earlier using the $ npm install -g @ionic/cli command but it wasn't working but as soon as I removed the -g it seemed to download perfectly, I would like to know the cause.

Thanks,

Comment: Install NVM then Install Nodejs Stable Version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux or MacOS try:

```
$ sudo npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

Instead of:

```
$ npm install -g @ionic/cli
```